# magento 2 Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed

Tags: configuration, themes, magento2

After Theme installation and applied the theme in backend (**System-> Configuration-> General-> Theme**),clear the cache and refresh front end it gives an error in magento2.the error like below

```
Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed
#0 /var/www/demos/magento2new/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Fallback/Rule/Theme.php(69): Magento\Framework\View\Design\Fallback\Rule\Simple->getPatternDirs(Array)
#1 /var/www/demos/magento2new/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/FileResolution/Fallback/Resolver/Simple.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Design\Fallback\Rule\Theme->getPatternDirs(Array)
#2 /var/www/demos/magento2new/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/FileResolution/Fallback/Resolver/Simple.php(64): Magento\Framework\View\Design\FileResolution\Fallback\Resolver\Simple->resolveFile(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Design\Fallback\Rule\Theme), 'i18n/en_US.csv', Array)
#3 /var/www/demos/magento2new/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/FileResolution/Fallback/LocaleFile.php(42): Magento\Framework\View\Design\FileResolution\Fallback\Resolver\Simple->resolve('locale', 'i18n/en_US.csv', 'frontend', Object(Magento\Theme\Model\Theme), 'en_US', NULL)
#4 /var/www/demos/magento2new/vendor/magento/framework/View/FileSystem.php(103): Magento\Framework\View\Design\FileResolution\Fallback\LocaleFile->getFile('frontend', Object(Magento\Theme\Model\Theme), 'en_US', 'i18n/en_US.csv')
```

added the `registration.php` in theme but front end is blankpage...

Comment: From first impression it looks like magento is not identifying registration.php file. Can you remove theme and place it back together with registration.php and run setup upgrade command ?

Comment: upgrade command is #php bin/magento setup:upgrade is it right?

Comment: php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade from Magento root.

Comment: On Magento Stackexchange: [“Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed”](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/100011/4115).

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a new theme, or trying to figure out why your newly installed theme is crashing your site, it may be due to a capitalization issue.  In linux, make sure the directory your theme is located in has the correct capitalization required for it to all work properly.  It is not guaranteed that the theme developer was using a linux system (they may have been using windows, and yes, its possible to run magento + php + windows although its a cludge).  This would allow the theme developer to ignore directory / filename capitalization, and possibly release a theme that isn't really compatible with a filesystem that forces capitalization.

In linux you can have ALL of these files in one directory...

- test.php
- Test.php
- TEST.php
- tEst.php
- test.PHP

you get the idea....

$theme->getFullPath() may output something like /design/Yourcompany/Yourtheme but your actual path may be design/Yourcompany/yourtheme.  That capitalization is very strict on linux systems, and will cause all kinds of headaches.

Its also very important that the registration.php file has the same capitalization that the directory, and the output of $theme->getFullPath() has.  All of this has to match.

If you intend on debugging $theme->getFullPath(), its in the \Magento\Framework\View\Design\Fallback\Rule\Simple class.

Comment: This was not the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

When you are adding or editing product then Go to Design section and change layout option.
[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, fixing theme folder permission solved the problem

Comment: @cjohansson maybe you have deleted a theme without removing it from database? or the theme registration file is not correct

Comment: Nope none of that is the issue

Answer (score 1):

Delete Row having theme not defined in your system in theme table ..

if you created new theme it should be shown here...  delete another theme which is not active or unnecessary..

Answer (score 1):

From the error seems that you have a theme configured which doesn't exist on the file-system (any more).
It can be easily fixed by selecting a valid theme instead. 
Go to Content -> Configuration, select the scope (global, website, store_view) and change the theme.After you've done that you should also remove it from Content -> Themes.

(OR)

This can also be the case if your theme directory does not have the proper permissions

Comment: This solved our issue. We had a old theme there that wasn't used but still was not available in the file-system anymore and apparently Magento 2 will crash product updates in those cases. We resolved it by deleting the old theme, re-selected our current theme and cleaned caches

Answer (score 0):

**Steps:**

1. Change the value for theme_id for the current store:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'design/theme/theme_id';
   ```

   UPDATE Stable theme id here.
2. Flush configuration cache:

   ```
   php bin\magento cache:flush config
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The error happens when you remove a theme folder of Magento 2 in app/design/frontend// , but not remove theme data from database.

In Magento 2 admin section, go to: Content => Design => Configuration and change theme to the valid theme will fix this error

Another solution is to remove invalid theme from database using this MySQL command

```
mysql -u <dbuser> -p -e "delete from <dbname>.theme where theme_path ='<Vendorname>/<themename>' AND area ='frontend' limit 1"
```

**Reference source:** https://magentip.com/required-parameter-theme_dir-was-not-passed-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

at contect->configuration-> select luma theme on your store save &
at content->Themes delete custom theme due to which you are facing issue
after that select theme which you want this error will not appear